# ¿Cómo puedo traducir la siguiente oración, ya que no entiendo cómo se está utilizando el *without*?

Tags: traducción

> Formally, machine learning can be defined as the study of systems
>   that can learn from data without being explicitly programmed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`without` no tiene un significado especial en esa oración.

> the study of systems that can learn from data **without** being explicitly programmed

Puede ser traducido como

> el estudio de sistemas que pueden aprender a partir de datos **sin** haber sido explícitamente programados.

Es posible que los tiempos verbales estén causando más confusión en la traducción que el `without`. Es traducción no es única, y la oración podría ser traducida como

> sistemas que pueden aprender a partir de datos sin **ser** explícitamente programados.

Comment: gracias solo falto lo de data pero si ya entendí muchas gracias

Comment: @diego - Creo yo que no es bueno para el sitio dar respuesta cuando la pregunta se va a cerrar.  Por otra parte creo que la razón de cierre está mal -- esta pregunta se debe plantear en ELL or ELU, y me parece que el diálogo de cierre permite recomendar un traslado. // A propósito, me parece que una mejor explicación de la idea de esta frase sería algo así como: el estudio de sistemas que pueden realizar aprendizaje a partir de datos dados, en lugar de presentar resultados explícitamente programados.  No son los *datos* que no están explícitamente programados, sino los resultados que...

Comment: salen del proceso de "aprendizaje".

Comment: @aparente001 Posiblemente (me suena que hay una discusión en Meta sobre ello), pero esta pregunta es de hace un par de años (Abril 2015), y acaba de ser cerrada (puesta en la cola de rev. tras un edit. Cerrada dos días atrás). Es decir, llevaba abierta todo este tiempo y supongo que el edit hizo que saliese más arriba en la lista de "preguntas recientes". Alguien la vio y se dio cuenta de que era offtopic por no ofrecer traducción y votó para cerrar. No creo que merezca la pena darle más vueltas a esta pregunta.

Comment: @Diego - Bien.  En Meta yo propuse que no contestemos preguntas mal planteadas, porque así es la norma en ELU.  Me parece interesante esta pregunta dentro del contexto de del tema en Meta.  Pero está bien, no habrá falta de otras preguntas para explorar ese tema.